# Probability distributions of bounded measurement results?

Tags: experimental-physics, probability, measurements

Say that I am measuring a length very inaccurately.  For instance, I might measure $1m$ with an uncertainty of $50cm$.  If I model the probability distribution as a Gaussian with $\sigma=50cm$, I run into the unfortunate problem that this would predict some measurements that are negative length, even though a negative length could never be measured.

Is there a "more correct" probability distribution that I could use to model this sort of a measurement?  Is there something fundamentally wrong with the way I'm proposing this scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is difficult if not impossible to answer unless more detail is given as to how the value $100\pm50\,\rm cm $ was obtained.

As a simple example here is one scenario where the distribution can be Gaussian with meaningful negative values.

The lengths of two ropes produced, in different parts of a country, in a rope making competition are approximately $100\,\rm m$ long.

Measurements at the two sites result in their lengths being found to be $500.3\pm 0.3\,\rm m$ and $499.3\pm 0.4\,\rm m$.

The difference between the lengths of the ropes is $(500.3-499.3)\pm(\sqrt{0.3^2+0.4^2}) = 1.0\pm0.5\,\rm m$.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct that, from a strict perspective, this is an issue. However, I think if you reported 1m +-50cm you would cause little confusion (especially if your provided the measurement method), but if you did some complicated post processing to update the distribution based on the knowledge the length cannot be <0 you would just confuse people far more.

I have seen papers reporting on the efficiency of devices where the paper says things like "efficiency of 97+/-5%. These were professional published papers, and they didn't feel any need to start worrying about the fact that efficiencies over 100% were nonsense - because the 97=/-5% communicated what they did clearly enough. If they did some kind of complicated model where they cut the tail off, renormalized, calculated the new centre and finally quoted something like 95+-/4% then a whole extra page of the paper would be dedicated to the post-processing and it would frankly come across as weird.

So if you want to be clearly understood, I wouldn't do anything extra. If you want to be talking about a fundamentally correct way of talking about your uncertainty then the problem isn't actually anything to do with your error being so large, its fundamentally built into the Gaussian distribution itself - it has tails that extend forever. A measurement of 1m give or take 1nm has some tail reaching into negative distance if we take the Gaussian as the model.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there something fundamentally wrong with the way I'm proposing this scenario?

Yes. You are proposing a Gaussian Distribution for something that cannot be a Gaussian Distribution.

The distribution of your measurements will be a function of the measurement process. Measurement errors or noise don't appear magically out of thin air. There is a physical mechanism that creates them and that mechanism determines what the distribution of the error looks like. If you postulate that the  measurement result can not be negative   then the distribution cannot be a Gaussian.

For example, let's assume you measure distance with a magnetic probe and the probe current is contaminated with a lot of additive Gaussian white noise. Then the distribution will indeed be Gaussian and you will indeed see some negative measurements.